# async_read_some return

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Is there a way in Boost::ASIO to know if `async_read_some` wont return in a particular time period to call a function without closing the socket? Usually `async_read_some()` wont return if there is no more data to be transfered to the buffer.

```
 _socket->async_read_some(
     boost::asio::buffer(this->reply, sizeof(this>reply)),
     boost::bind(
         &TCP_IP_Connection::dataProcess,
         this,
         boost::asio::placeholders::error,
         boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
     )
 );
```

Comment: It can be accomplished with the use of a timer.  It may be worth taking the time to read through the official Boost.Asio examples provided [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/blocking_tcp_client.cpp) and [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/async_tcp_client.cpp) to get a better understanding of the approach.

Comment: Thanks but I dont want to close the connection.

Comment: Then do not call `socket::close()`?  The _approach_ is in the example.

Comment: Could you explain a little better about what your concern is here and what you are trying to do?

Comment: This is a part of a TCP client program. I try to read response of a command from the server.When all data from stream is read async_read_some() blocks until there is some data to transfer to the buffer. So I want to make sure, during this blocking state the server is still connected, some how. As per earlier comments, I'm reading the examples from Boost about time-out.

Comment: @JishnuUNair `async_read_some` does not block, it is asynchronous as its name implies. Furthermore the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html) clearly states it **returns immediately**. Your question is not clear, please edit it and clarify. Perhaps posting some more pseudo code may help?

Answer (score 0):

`async_read_some` always returns immediately.

If you're talking about the handler (callback), if you close the socket before it returns, then I *think* the handler gets called with `asio::error::operation_aborted`. If you handle this scenario then maybe you don't need to worry about if you're connected or not.